# What about AngularJS 1.2 release and support scheme?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, versioning

One can read [here](http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/07/angularjs-10-12-roadmap.html)

> AngularJs 1.2 version was expected by September 2012

Well, we are all programmers and know what happen with projects timelines ;)

**BUT** those who want adopt AngularJS and invest consider amount of money on it could be worried due to the statement in that same blog post that said:

> 1.0.x will receive only bug fixes backported from 1.1.x branch and will be supported until 1.2 is released

Basically the lack of a roadmap mean that suddenly our AngularJs 1.0.x app could turn unsupported when the new 1.2 version come up, what could happen... when?

Thanks in advance for any info regards expected release date of AngularJS 1.2 ;)

Comment: This question is probably better off in the AngularJS google forums, which are a bit more 'official'. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/angular

Comment: Already [there](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/angular/qqfjHjVY9oA/discussion), just want put it here too cos could be people that don't read AngularJS Google Group but yes stackoverflow. In case that someone reply there, at Google Group, I will put here the result for better visibility.

Comment: Today Angular 1.2 was announced and as you can read [here](http://blog.angularjs.org/2013/08/angularjs-120-rc1-spooky-giraffe.html) (the PS part) 1.0.x version seem be unsupported.